# AVPlayer doesn't resume playback on endinterruption on iPhone but does so on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer, avaudiosession

I'm writing a radio app for both iPhone and iPad and am running into some weird behaviour when handling pausing and playing the audio with interruptions. I'm using the AVAudioSessionDelegate methods `beginInterruption` and `endInterruption` to respectively `pause` and `play` the AVPlayer. Below is the relevant `play` code.

Now, the following situations seem to happen consistently:

1. **On iPad:** If I force an interruption (Facetime call), `beginInterruption` is called as expected and playback stops. If the interruption stops, `endInterruption` is called as expected, and the playback resumes as expected.
2. **On iPhone:** Pressing the play and pause button, triggers `pause` and `play` exactly the same as `beginInterruption` and `endInterruption` would. Playback behaves as expected.
3. **On iPhone:** Forcing an interruption (by calling the phone), calls `endInterruption` as expected and playback pauses as expected. However, when the interruption is finished, `beginInterruption` is called as expected, `play` is called as expected, *it actually reaches and executes the `[self.player play]` line*, but playback **does not resume!** I hear nothing.

Situation 3 above is extremely weird, so I'm wondering if I may have overlooked something. Any ideas?

**`Play` code**

```
- (void)play { 
NSError* error = nil;
AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [currentAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
if(error){
    DLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else {
    DLog(@"Current Key Status: %i", keyStatus);
    if(keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded){
        DLog(@"Continue playing source: %@", self.source);
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
        if (error) {
            DLog(@"Error during play while setting AVAudioSessionCategory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
        if (error) {
            DLog(@"Error during play while setting AVAudioSessionCategory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
        if(backgroundTaskID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskID];
        }
        backgroundTaskID = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

        [self.player play];
        [self setStatus:kNPOMediaPlayerStatusPlaying];
    }
    else {
        DLog(@"PlaySource: %@", self.source);
        [self playSource:self.source];
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known bug in iOS, which requires some careful work-arounds in the applicationDidBecomeActive to handle beginInterruption. Sadly, I couldn't figure out another solution.

Comment: Hey, can you give some direction on what is the workaround you mentioned? Facing similar problem, can't find solution

Comment: @gavrix Basically used a lot of state management that keeps track of things like 'playing', 'paused', 'interruptedByCall', etc… using booleans. When the app is put back in the foreground, the code checks all the states to check what it should do. Basically very error-prone behaviour and very dependent on what you're making.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Issue disappeared after I implemented remote control event handling. I called `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];`when starting playback.