# Resuming AVPlayer after phone call

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, swift5, avaudiosession

There appears to be many solutions on SO addressing this yet none of those solutions have worked for me. I'm currently using Swift 5. I have a AVPlayer playing an animation (that loops) in my ViewController. When a call comes in through CallKit, regardless of whether I answer or decline the call, the animation played by the AVPlayer does not resume after the call has been dealt with. The interruption handler seems to be called *before* an interruption but usually doesn't get called *after* the interruption.

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            prepareBGVideo()
            ...
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)),
                name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                object: nil)
            ...
        }        

       func prepareBGVideo() {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "animation", ofType:"mp4") else {
                print("video not found")
                return
            }

            let item = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(loopVideoBG),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: item)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption(notification:)), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)
            avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
            avPlayerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            avPlayer.volume = 0
            avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none
            avPlayer.play()

            view.backgroundColor = .clear
            avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
            avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = isIPAD ? AVLayerVideoGravity.resize : AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill // Changed from AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect to AVLayerVideoGravity.resize so that video fits iPad screen

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(willEnterForeground),
                                                   name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                                                   object: nil)
        }

        @objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
            guard let info = notification.userInfo,
                let typeValue = info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
                let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
                    return
            }
            if type == .began {
                // Interruption began, take appropriate actions (save state, update user interface)
                self.avPlayer.pause()
            } else if type == .ended {
                guard let optionsValue =
                    info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else {
                        return
                }
                let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
                if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
                    // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
                    self.avPlayer.play()
                }
            }
        }

        /// Resume video while app wake up from background
        @objc func willEnterForeground() {
            avPlayer.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            JPUtility.shared.performOperation(0.1) {
                self.avPlayer.play()
            }
        }

        @objc func loopVideoBG() {
            avPlayer.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            avPlayer.play()
        }
```

Here are all the solutions that I have tried:

1. [Waiting two seconds before calling `self.avPlayer.play()` in `if options.contains(.shouldResume){}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52512833/11970984)
2. [Setting `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive` to false when interruption begins and then setting it ot true when interruption ends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57282652/11970984). The issue with this approach is that the `if interruption == .ended {}` block doesn't always get invoked so setting `setActive` had no effect.
3. [Setting `AVAudioSession` playback category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38809220/11970984). My animation doesn't have audio anyway.

I have seen mentions of resuming playback in `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` but some advised against this. Would this be considered good practice?

Is there a way to ensure that the `else if type == .ended {}` block gets executed? Or perhaps a workaround that works more reliably than observing `AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification`?

Comment: Have you tried `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: "There is no guarantee that a begin interruption will have a corresponding end interruption. Your app needs to be aware of a switch to a foreground running state or the user pressing a Play button. In either case, determine whether your app should reactivate its audio session." – https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I tried viewWillAppear and vewDidAppear as well and they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this but creating a shared `VideoPlayer` class that contained references to all the screen that had animations.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

    class VideoPlayer: NSObject {

        static var shared: VideoPlayer = VideoPlayer()

        var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
        var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

        weak var vcForConnect:ConnectVC?
        weak var vcForList:ListVC?

        override init() {
            super.init()
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "animation", ofType:"mp4") else {
                print("video not found")
                return
            }
            avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
            avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            avPlayer.volume = 0
            avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none
            loopVideo(videoPlayer: avPlayer)
            avPlayer.play()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption(notification:)), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)

        }

        deinit {
            avPlayer.pause()
        }

        @objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
            guard let info = notification.userInfo,
                let typeValue = info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
                let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue) else {
                    return
            }
            if type == .began {
                // Interruption began, take appropriate actions (save state, update user interface)
                self.avPlayer.pause()
            } else if type == .ended {
                guard let optionsValue =
                    info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey] as? UInt else {
                        return
                }
                let options = AVAudioSession.InterruptionOptions(rawValue: optionsValue)
                if options.contains(.shouldResume) {
                    // Interruption Ended - playback should resume
                    self.avPlayer.play()
                }
            }
        }

        func resumeAllAnimations() {
            self.avPlayer.play()
            if vcForList?.avPlayer != nil {
                vcForList?.avPlayer.play()
            }
            if vcForConnect?.avPlayer != nil {
                vcForConnect?.avPlayer.play()
            }
            if vcForConnect?.avPlayerBG != nil {
                vcForConnect?.avPlayerBG.play()
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

I then resume the animations by calling `resumeAllAnimations()` in `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` in `AppDelegate.swift` like so:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        VideoPlayer.shared.resumeAllAnimations()
        ...
}
```