# Resume AVAudioPlayer after phone call not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, avaudioplayer

There are some seemingly similar questions already on SO, but after hours of searching and experimenting with my code, I have been unable to find a clear answer. The closest thing I could find was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840435/5225549) which alludes to a "known bug" 4 years ago, but does not elaborate on how to address it.

I have an audioPlayer class that is playing an audio file with AVAudioPlayer and listening for the `AVAudioSessionDelegate` methods `beginInterruption` and `endInterruption`. I know that `endInterruption` is not guaranteed so I store a boolean in `beginInterruption` and handle restarting the audio playback in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

This all works perfectly as expected if the phone receives a call and the user declines it or lets it go to voicemail. As soon as my app goes back into the active state, audio playback resumes.

**Here's where I'm getting weird behavior:** If the user *answers* the call, once they hang up everything *seems* to work as expected but no sound comes out through either the headphones or the speakers.

I can verify that the audio is technically *playing* by printing its volume and currentTime every second, but the sound isn't coming out.

If I wait for 20-40 seconds, the audio suddenly cuts in and becomes audible, as if it had been silently playing in the background.

After more debugging, I noticed that `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` remains `true` for these 20-40 seconds of silence, before suddenly changing to `false` and letting the audio play.

I subscribed to the `AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification` to see if I could detect this change, but it never gets called, even when `.secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` changes from `true` to `false`.

I even tried *explicitly* setting `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` in the method that resumes playback of the audio, but the behavior did not change.

Lastly, I tried setting a timer to delay the resume for 10 seconds after `applicationDidBecomeActive`, but the behavior did not change.

**So, why does it seem that the phone call is not relinquishing control of the audio session back to my app?**

Thanks for taking a look!

---

Code:

**AVAudioSession setup in `init()`:**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleAudioHintChange), name: AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handleAudioInterruption), name: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, object: nil)

do {
  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers)
  print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
  do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, withOptions: .NotifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    print("AVAudioSession is Active")
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Notification handlers:**

```
///////////////////////////////////
// This never gets called :( //////

func handleAudioHintChange(notification: NSNotification) {
  print("audio hint changed")
}
///////////////////////////////////

func handleAudioInterruption(notification: NSNotification) {
  if notification.name != AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification || notification.userInfo == nil{
    return
  }

  if let typeKey = notification.userInfo [AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
  let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: typeKey) {
    switch type {
      case .Began:
        print("Audio Interruption Began")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"wasInterrupted")

      case .Ended:
        print("Audio Interuption Ended")
    }
  }
}
```

**App Delegate:**

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
  if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("wasInterrupted")) {
    audioPlayer.resumeAudioFromInterruption()
  }
}
```

**Restart function:**

```
// This works great if the phone call is declined
func resumeAudioFromInterruption() {
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("wasInterrupted")
  do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    print("AVAudioSession is Active")
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
  thisFunctionPlaysMyAudio()
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to do the same, although I didn't use any options in the `setActive` method.

There seem to be a bug in iOS 9.3.1 that doesn't resume playback of the AVAudioPlayer after the phone call ends.

Here is a snippet of what solved it for me: (Sorry for the Objective-C)

```
- (void)handleInterruption:(NSNotification *) notification{
    if (notification.name != AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification || notification.userInfo == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;

    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification]) {

        if ([[info valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan]]) {
            NSLog(@"InterruptionTypeBegan");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"InterruptionTypeEnded");

            //*The* Workaround - Add a small delay to the avplayer's play call; Without the delay, the playback will *not* be resumed
            //
            //(I didn't play much with the times, but 0.01 works with my iPhone 6S 9.3.1)
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"playing");
                [_player play];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I added a small delay to the player's play call, and it worked.

You can find the full Demo project I made here:
https://github.com/liorazi/AVAudioSessionWorkaround

I submitted a radar to Apple, hopefully it'll get fixed on the next release.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm glad it's possible a bug and not just me being crazy. Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure that I also attempted a delay with no luck. I'll double check and try again this week and let you know how it goes...

Comment: Not yet, sorry. I fully intend to revisit this but there are other things higher up on the list that we've decided to prioritize. I'll comment here as soon as I get a chance to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Use this after you're done with Audio.

AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, withOptions: .NotifyOthersOnDeactivation)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Try to reload player after interruption:

```
    func interruptionNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let type = notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
      let interruption = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: type) else {
        return
    }
    if interruption == .ended && playerWasPlayingBeforeInterruption {
      player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: radioStation.url))
      play()
    }
  }
```