# secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint issue in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After updating my device to iOS 13 today, I noticed that the background music in our app does not always return when the app is brought back to the foreground. Upon closer inspection, AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint is sometimes returning true, and sometimes returning false, even when no other music sources are playing.

If I put a breakpoint in the AppDelegate, AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint will return false as expected every time. I even put multiple print statements for this, and prior to the breakpoint, the result is true, and after stepping over the next print statement, it is false.

I am simply checking like this in AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
{

     if AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint
     {
```

This worked as expected in iOS 12. Any ideas? It is strange that it is inconsistent. Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662959/resume-avaudioplayer-after-phone-call-not-working, along with this: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44028&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1569099140826000&usg=AFQjCNHEFOPoCNFeHJ1HT6ki3YomghxVUg. That said, this problem seems to be much worse in iOS 13.

Comment: My app takes the approach of polling `secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` once a second. We've discovered that on iPhoneX style devices, swiping up from the bottom to "wake up" the home bar (i.e. not even enough to resign active) will cause `secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` to be true for a short period.

Comment: Not sure if your issue is the same as mine (mine seems to be specific to the iPhoneX family). Anyway I have filed a report with Apple `FB7448162`.